# multi-domain setup: template entry.url includes index.php

Tags: url, config, multi-environment

`.htaccess` is working fine. If I manually type `url.com/about` it shows the page. If I manually type `url.com/asdf` it shows 404 template page.

`url.com/index.php/testPathInfo` shows `success`

general.php has

```
return array(
    '*' => array(
        'omitScriptNameInUrls' => 'true',
    ),
...
```

but when templates contain `{{ url('about') }}` or `{{ entry.url }}` I get `url.com/index.php?p=whatever-this-is-supposed-to-be`

I'm probably missing something easy and obvious but I've been staring at it all morning. Could it still be the mod_rewrite enabled thing even though it's rewriting fine?

.htaccess content

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /

   # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
   RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

AuthType Basic
AuthName "*DEV*"
AuthUserFile /home/username/public_html/dev/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Comment: Can you share your public `.htaccess` file contents?

Comment: Also, the title mentions multi-domain... can you clarify how that applies here?

Comment: @BradBell added .htaccess content to original question. I don't know if multi-domain applies here but thought I'd add the info. I'm currently working in "dev" subdomain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OMG I'm so angry at myself!

Not `'omitScriptNameInUrls' => 'true',`

but `'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,`